# "Read-only mode" banner is illegible due to color scheme

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

The Stack Exchange network was [put into read-only mode today](http://stackstatus.net/post/125387022934/read-only-test-august-1-2015) for a failover test.  A banner was posted on each site to advise users of this.  However, on English.SE (and Meta.English.SE), the banner consists of white text on a beige background, and is nearly impossible to read, or even notice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Agreed; that is *not* a colo[u]r-scheme for the faint-hearted! Changing it to something less anti-social...